# Setting the text of a TextView when the desired input is larger than ~4000 in String length()

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to `setText(string)` on a `TextView` component and I am not seeing the text I set.  The input `String` is larger than 4000 in `length()`.  I find that if I reduce the text size, the text will display.

How can I `setText(string)` on a `TextView` with all of the input `String` visible without changing the text size of the `TextView`?

Do I have to split the input `String` and use multiple `TextView` objects?

How will I know if the input `String` will be too large and not be seen, as my `TextView` may be filled with dynamic text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess - you have a Samsung phone? Samsung saw fit to modify the operating system to have an implicit maximum size on all TextViews. Why? No idea. But if you specify the length with `android:maxLength`, it'll work just fine.

See here: [How can I debug a seemingly hardware-dependent issue with my Android app without access to the hardware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508831/how-can-i-debug-a-seemingly-hardware-dependent-issue-with-my-android-app-without/3577934#3577934)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Sony Ericsson Xperia.
I have solved it by using EditText with inputType="none" and editable="false"
I hope it will help you.